# How do I selectively visualize data in a categorical column in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, categorical-data

I have a dataset with "Status" as one of its columns. In the status variable, the data is either "Employed" or "Left."

I want to visualize only the "Left" entries of the "Status" column.

Currently, I'm only able to visualize both "Employed" and "Left"  using this code:

```
ggplot(data=employee_data) + geom_point(aes(x=satisfaction, y=last_evaluation, color=status))
```

If I want to isolate only those in "Left" category, how do I do that?

[image]

Comment: `data=filter(employee_data, status == 'Left')`?

Comment: `data=employee_data[employee_data$Status=='Left']`?

Comment: Hi @jdobres, thanks for the response. Tried this, but it does not work. ggplot(data=filter(employee_data, status == "Left") + 
         geom_point(aes(x=satisfaction, y=last_evaluation, color=status))

Comment: Please add an minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @NoelJosephPadilla, if you are indeed using `filter(employee_data, status == "Left")` and plotting that with `ggplot(..., aes(color=status))`, you're saying that you still see points plotted within `status == "Employed"`? ***Really***, please include sample data such as `dput(head(employee_data,20))` in a code block in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you might have made a typo. Should be `ggplot(data=filter(employee_data, status == "Left")) + ...`

Comment: @jdobres I revisited the code and it worked now! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with a simple filter.

```
ggplot(data = filter(employee_data, status == "left")) + 
geom_point(aes(x = satisfaction, y = last_evaluation, color = status))
```

Using the iris dataset, you can see the output

```
ggplot(data = filter(iris, Species == "setosa")) + 
geom_point(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length, color = Species))
```

[image: filtered plot]